# How to distribute values between records

Tags: algorithm, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have value 1000 and table:

```
table
(
  Id int (PK),
  Percent float,
  Value int
)
```

I have to distribute 1000 for every record in this table for field Value according to two law (two separated strategy):

1) equal distribution strategy

2) % of distribution strategy

**Input by strategy 1)**

```
Id  Percent Value
1,  -       0
2,  -       0
3,  -       0
```

**Output**

```
Id  Percent Value
1,  -       333
2,  -       333
3,  -       334
```

**Input by strategy 2)**

```
 Id  Percent Value
 1,  10%       0
 2,  90%       0
```

**Output**

```
Id  Percent Value
1,  10%       100
2,  90%       900
```

Could anyone explain an elegant way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some example data illustrating your requirement.

Comment: @grimmig don't worry about this (round(1000/3) and 99.99) - rest can be added to the last record, thanks for remark.

Comment: With 6 rows you will end up with ids 1-5 having value 166 and id 6 with value 170. Sure you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @valueToDistribute float;
SET @valueToDistribute = 100;

DECLARE @rest int;
DECLARE @temp int;
SET @temp = 0;
DECLARE @error float
SET @error = 0;

DECLARE @tableToDistribute table
(
    id                  int
    ,MaxValue           int 
    ,InitialValue       int 
    ,DistributedValue   int
);

INSERT @tableToDistribute values(1, 0, 0, 0);
INSERT @tableToDistribute values(2, 0, 0, 0);

INSERT @tableToDistribute values(3, 0, 0, 0);
INSERT @tableToDistribute values(4, 0, 0, 0);
INSERT @tableToDistribute values(5, 0, 0, 0);
INSERT @tableToDistribute values(6, 0, 0, 0);
--INSERT @tableToDistribute values(7, 0, 0, 0);
--INSERT @tableToDistribute values(8, 0, 0, 0);
--INSERT @tableToDistribute values(9, 0, 0, 0);


SET   @rest = @valueToDistribute;

WITH Count_CTE (Id, [Percent], MaxId)
AS
(
   SELECT 
          Id
        , [Percent] = CAST(@valueToDistribute / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tableToDistribute) / 100.00 as float)
        , [MaxId] = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @tableToDistribute)
    FROM @tableToDistribute
)
UPDATE t 
    SET
       @error = @error + (cte.[Percent] * @valueToDistribute) - ROUND(cte.[Percent] * @valueToDistribute, 0)
      ,@temp = 
        case
            when ROUND(@error, 5) <> 0.00000
                then 
                    case 
                        when t.Id = cte.MaxId then @rest --ROUND(cte.[Percent] * @valueToDistribute, 0) + FLOOR(@error)
                        else ROUND(cte.[Percent] * @valueToDistribute, 0)
                    end 
            else  ROUND(cte.[Percent] * @valueToDistribute, 0)      
        end 
      ,DistributedValue = @temp
      ,@rest = @rest - @temp
FROM @tableToDistribute t 
    inner join Count_CTE cte on t.Id = cte.Id;


SELECT
*
FROM @tableToDistribute
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET Value =( SELECT 1000/COUNT(Value) from yourtable )

UPDATE yourtable SET Value =( Value * Percent )
```

Not sure how to handle rounding errors, though.

edit: maybe in the first case with a second statement that adds the missing numbers to the last row.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET Value = Value + 1000 -( SELECT SUM(Value) from yourtable) where id= (SELECT MAX(Id) from yourtable)
```

But this isn't good, since the last row can end up with a much bigger number... you will end up with a significantly larger number than the rest. (try running the query with 6 input rows...)

Comment: What are you thinking about restriction, for example MaxValue - the additional field in the table? Equal distribution is not based on restriction, but we cannot add to value more then we have at MaxValue field

Comment: I got a bad feeling about doing this in the database, but it could be done. Consider this: with integers your rounding error will be 1 for each row. The value of the added rounding errors will be less than the total number of rows. So you can add 1 to each line with an id smaller than the rounding error.

Comment: good point of view about error (good direction). it is easier to add rest to the last record (it is not fairly for 1000/6 or 1000/8, but it's acceptable). see my answer.